# Extracting values from json request (which could possibly undefined)

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, aws-lambda, serverless-stack

I am trying to learn typescript/js and one of thing i am doing is implement a rest-api using aws-lambda (severless tack). Now, I need to extract body payload to either a construct or just assign those values to variables.

Lets say I am sending following request to signup a user

```
POST {{userApiEndpoint}}/signup HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json

{"username":{{username}},"password":{{password}}}
```

Now I want to extract this `username` and `password` from `event.body`. I have tried multiple things and everytime i am getting errors of `string | undefined can't be assigned to string` or something similar.

Things that i have tried

```
export interface User {
  username: string | undefined;
  password: string | undefined;
}
```

Option 1: `const newUser = event.body? as User;` got an error that says `Cannot find name 'as'`

Option 2: `const newUser = event.body as User;` got an error which says `Conversion of type 'string | undefined' to type 'User' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.`

Option 3: `const body =  JSON.parse(event.body);` got an error which says `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.`

I am not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 should work.

**Edit:** unless you have explicitly typed your `event` type as `APIGatewayProxyEventV2`, in which case the body is of type [`string | undefined`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/9e6ba0f71277e6bec41151bf1d83c17d8f15b243/types/aws-lambda/trigger/api-gateway-proxy.d.ts#L124), and the user is:

`user = JSON.parse(event.body ?? "") as User`

```js
export interface User {
  username: string | undefined;
  password: string | undefined;
}

// event explicitly typed as APIGatewayProxyEventV2
// the body is typed as string | undefined
const event = {body: '{"username": "foo", "password": "bar"}'} as Record<string, string | undefined>
const user = JSON.parse(event.body ?? "") as User
console.log(user.password)

// Option 3
// the body is typed as any
const event1 = {body: '{"username": "foo", "password": "bar"}'} as Record<string, any>
const user1 = JSON.parse(event1.body) as User
console.log(user1.password)
```

Comment: I have this line `const newUser = JSON.parse(event.body) as User;` and it gave me same error i.e., `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
(property) APIGatewayProxyEventV2.body?: string | undefined`

Comment: @EmAe `user = JSON.parse(event.body ?? "") as User` see earlier edited answer.  The OP did not contain the `APIGatewayProxyEventV2` type reference.